# Instagram Business Account

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps, instagram

I am using lumia 540 with windows 10 latest build. I am trying to use Instagram Business Account. But i don't have option to Switch Business Account. I am not sure Business Account option is available on windows phone or not. Please suggest me best solution.

Comment: Have you checked under profile/settings. The option is there if you are using the official instagram app. Also, i think the option works if you have linked to your facebook account, so try doing that and see if the option appears

Comment: Yeah! i checked all setting under profile. Yeah i am using official instagram app. And my facebook account linked. I think business account option is not for windows phone app.

Comment: No, thing is, I had it before on my Windows Phone. Just that i unistalled the app because its still a bit too buggy, and it accumulates size with each use...!!! Try uninstalling then reinstalling it and see if anything changes

Comment: I have the same problem and I created my business account on an apple device. Then I switched to Windows Phone and the statistics were not available. They have still not made the update for WP phone 10, you can only see the contact button. So the solution is to wait a little longer and the update will hopefully come! Greets